# fxFlex.xs fxLayout.xs and more not working in Angular 8.2.7

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

Trying to use fxFlex.xs, fxFlex.md, fxFlex.lg with Angular FlexLayout nothing happens after resize only the default fxFlex="with some value" works for all the screen sizes.

I tried finding solution stumbled upon this https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1111

Didn't find any answer. Can somebody help me what I am missing here